# Flex lexical analyzer not behaving as expected

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm trying to use Flex to match basic patterns and print something.

```
%%
 
^[^qA-Z]*q[a-pr-z0-9]*4\n           {printf("userid1, userid2  \n"); return 1;}

%% 
int yywrap(void){return 1;}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
             {
             ++argv, --argc;  /* skip over program name */
             if ( argc > 0 )
                     yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
             else
                     yyin = stdin;

             while (yylex());
             }
```

Resolved dumb question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, so I'll focus on the immediate issue, which is your last pattern:

```
^[^qA-Z]*q[a-pr-z0-9]*4[a-pr-z0-9]*4[a-pr-z0-9]*\n
```

That pattern starts by matching `[^qA-Z]*`, which is any number of anything which is not a `q` nor a capital letter (`A-Z`). Then it matches a `q`.

Here it's worth considering all the things which are not a `q` nor a capital letter (`A-Z`). Obviously, that includes lower-case letters such as `s` (other than `q`). It also includes  digits. And it includes any other character: punctuation, whitespace, even control characters. In particular, it includes a newline character.

So when you type

```
10s10<newline>
```

That certainly could be the start of the last pattern. The scanner hasn't yet seen a `q` so it doesn't know whether the pattern will eventually match, but it hasn't yet failed. So it keeps on reading more characters, including more newlines.

When you eventually type a `q`, the scanner can continue with the rest of the pattern. Depending on what you type next, it might or might not be able to continue. If, as seems likely, your input eventually fails to match the pattern, the lexer will fall back to the longest successful match, which is the first pattern. At that point, it will perform the first action

Negative character classes need to be used with a bit of caution. It's s easy to fall into the trap of thinking that "not ..." only includes "reasonable" input. But it includes everything. Often, as in this case, you'll want to at least exclude newlines.,

Comment: The 6 rules starting with the ^ are supposed to match a string with either one q or one 4 BUT they cant both occur exactly once. Those strings can only have lowercase letters and digits. Can I email you? This whole lexical analysis thing is new to me and so is stackoverflow lol. I don't get why it doesn't just match the first pattern tho, if it's ordered by precedence.

Comment: So I guess I can try negate new line also..?

Comment: @sid11k Flex (like most lexer generators) always uses the pattern that produces the longest match. The order only matters in case of ties. So it won't produce a match for the first pattern until it knows that none of the other rules produce a longer match.

Comment: "Often, you'll want to at" I think you forgot to finish this sentence.

Comment: @sepp2k ohh okay i gotchu! i was struggling reading documentation it was getting on my nerves even tho it aint that complicated lmao

Comment: @sepp2k: I finished the sentence. But the SO app didn't send it all (and what it sent, it sent late).